# In views.py file ==> category_posts = Post.object.filter(category=cat) returns an empty query set. The 'Post' model has sample posts with categories

Tags: python, django, web-development-server

I am creating a blog application in django where i encountered this unusual issue. I am not being able to filter and display blog posts category wise. Please find my code below. Thanks in advance. I have spent two full days trying to figure this out and still
got nothing.

#### MODELS.py

This is the model which i have created for a blog post.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="uncategorized")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #return reverse('article-detail', args=(str(self.id)))
        return reverse('homepage')
```

#### VIEWS.py

This is the view that i have created for a category wise blog posts.

```
def CategoryView(request,cat):
    category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=cat)
    return render(request,'categories.html',{'category_posts':category_posts})
```

#### URLS.py

The urls.py file.

`path('category/<str:cat>/', CategoryView, name = 'category'),`

#### CATEGORIES.html

This will be the final display page where the category_posts is displayed as an empty queryset. The for loop is unable to run because category_posts is an empty queryset. Single word categories are also empty(to rule out a slugify issue)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<ul>
{% for post in category_posts %}
<li>
    <div class="category">
      <a href="{% url 'category' post.category|slugify %}">{{ post.category }}</a>
    </div>
    <a href="{% url 'article-detail' post.pk  %}">
      <h3><b>{{ post.title }} </b></h3>
      <p class=card-date>
        <big>{{ post.author }}</big>
        <small>-{{ post.post_date }}</small>
      </p>
      <p class="excerpt-text">{{ post.body | slice:"100" |safe}}</p>
      <div class="article-thumbnail">
         <img src="{% static "images/bg.png" %}" alt="article-thumbnail" >
      </div>
     <div class="overlay">
    </a>
</li>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: If you try `category_posts = Post.objects.all()` do you show anything?

Comment: I see that you're using `post.category|slugify` in your template. This is converting the `Post` category to a slug (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#slugify). Your `category` field is declared as a `CharField` so maybe when converted to `slug` there are changes (if `category = 'Science'` it will be converted to `science` and filter won't return results). I would just remove the `|slugify` part.

Comment: @evergreen Yes i can see the posts if i do all(). Turns out this is a slugify issue. any other workaround to display two word categories,i.e., the categories which have a space between ?

Comment: @mtzd  Yes i can see the posts if i do all(). Turns out this is a slugify issue. any other workaround to display two word categories,i.e., the categories which have a space between ?

Comment: @Apaar, if you remove the slugify part, categories will come like `Science%20Fiction` or `Science+Fiction`. In your `CategoryView` class you can add `cat = cat.replace("%20", " ")` and `cat = cat.replace("+", " ")` before the line `category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=cat)`